# WPF Multicolumn combox with Headers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

I am trying to implement multi column combobox with header and contains search functionality.
I was able to achieve contains search filtering by extending the combobox control.
But i am unable to achieve Multi column display with Headers.
I have gone through most of the googled articles, but was of no help,

Below is my xaml of extended combobox control,

```
<wpf:FilteredComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                        IsEditable="True"
                                        IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchGridTemplate}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MaterialsList,
                                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                             AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                        StaysOpenOnEdit="True">

                                        <wpf:FilteredComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </wpf:FilteredComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    </wpf:FilteredComboBox>
```

Below is the data template which is applied to ItemTemplate property of FilteredComboboxControl, I need to modify this template such that the data are displayed in columns with headers.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SearchGridTemplate">
            <Border
                Margin="2"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid MinWidth="200">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="5"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="Part Number" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text=":" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="5"
                        Text="{Binding PartNumber}"
                        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Text,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                    <Border
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                        BorderBrush="Gray"
                        BorderThickness="0.5" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="5"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="Material Name" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text=":" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="5"
                        Text="{Binding Description}"
                        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Text,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I need to achieve something like this,
[image]

**By using Popup Template :** I am able to get the header and corresponding data. But if the value is large the headers are not syncying properly,

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MultiColumnSearchComboBox.MultiColumnSearchView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiColumnSearchComboBox"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Name="ucAdvCombo"
d:DesignHeight="80"
d:DesignWidth="600"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--  Toggle Button Template  -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid x:Name="gd">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                x:Name="Border"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="LightGray"
                BorderThickness="1"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
            <Border
                x:Name="Boredr1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="1"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="LightGray"
                BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
            <Path
                x:Name="Arrow"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Data="M 0 0 L 6 6 L 12 0 Z"
                Fill="Black"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" TextElement.Foreground="Orange" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                <Setter TargetName="Boredr1" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 5 5 L 10 0" />
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="gd" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!--  TextBox Template  -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!--  Style with Scroll Bar  -->
    <Style x:Key="EditableComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton
                            Name="ToggleButton"
                            ClickMode="Press"
                            Focusable="false"
                            Foreground="Black"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,
                                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Name="ContentSite"
                            Margin="3,3,23,3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        <TextBox
                            x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                            Margin="0,0,30,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            CaretBrush="Black"
                            Focusable="True"
                            FontFamily="B Koodak"
                            FontSize="15"
                            Foreground="Black"
                            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                            OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                            SelectionBrush="Gray"
                            Style="{x:Null}"
                            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                            Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <Popup
                            Name="Popup"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            AllowsTransparency="True"
                            Focusable="False"
                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                            Placement="Bottom"
                            PopupAnimation="Fade">
                            <Grid
                                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Background="#C8E6E6">
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Height="30"
                                        Padding="5"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        FontFamily="Arial"
                                        FontSize="14"
                                        FontWeight="Bold"
                                        Foreground="Black"
                                        Text="{Binding DataContext.ColumnNames[0],
                                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Border
                                    x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                                    MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                                <Grid
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Background="#C8E6E6">
                                    <TextBlock
                                        Padding="5"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        FontFamily="Arial"
                                        FontSize="14"
                                        FontWeight="Bold"
                                        Foreground="Black"
                                        Text="{Binding DataContext.ColumnNames[1],
                                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                    Margin="0,30,0,0"
                                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="True" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />-->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!--  combobox item style  -->
    <Style x:Key="Column_CmbItem" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="Border"
                        Margin="1,0,1,1"
                        Background="White">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox
        x:Name="Combobox"
        Width="550"
        Height="25"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        local:ComboBoxItemsSourceDecorator.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsCollectionView,
                                                                 ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                                                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                                 Mode=OneWay}"
        IsEditable="True"
        IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
        IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Column_CmbItem}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}"
        StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
        Style="{StaticResource EditableComboBoxStyle}"
        Text="{Binding FilterCriteria}"
        TextSearch.TextPath="FirstColumn">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid
                    x:Name="multiColumnComboBox"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="14"
                        Foreground="Black"
                        Text="{Binding FirstColumn}"
                        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="14"
                        Foreground="Black"
                        Text="{Binding SecondColumn}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

The result of above user control is shown below, Here we can see the first row second column data is moving towards column 1.
[image]

Below is the link where i have sample project of DataGrid inside Combobox, But i am unable to get the combobox displayed in the view,
[Extended Datagrid Inside Combobox](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WVMEJk5pwQt8zGghqN_M2phgw9OGH6Qj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: A suggestion : Why not create own userControl ?

Comment: I am stuck here, can you suggest me a way to do that, which can achieve my requirement.

Comment: Add an image of what you want so that i can customize the template per urrequirement

Comment: I have added the image to the ticket, which i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow your question.
When you drop down your combox, you want to see something like a listview.

If you take a look at the combobox template the bit you're interested in looks like:

```
      <Popup 
        Name="Popup"
        Placement="Bottom"
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Focusable="False"
        PopupAnimation="Slide">
        <Grid 
          Name="DropDown"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
          <Border 
            x:Name="DropDownBorder"
            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
          <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
      </Popup>
```

That popup is the thing appears when you click the combo to drop it down.
Notice that stackpanel with IsItemsHost=true.
That will host your items, which you can template with that datatemplate.
You also need something above them for the header.
Use a Grid and put it in the template above that scrollviewer. You will also need rowdefinitions on that existing grid so it gets some space.
Define columns and stick Labels or Borders with your headings in them in those columns.
Next problem you will have is getting the columns to line up.
You can do that by using shared size scope. As explained here:
https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/sharedsizegroup/

A popup is not in the same datacontext as the combo so you'd also need some way to set the headings. Assuming you really wanted to bind them. Simplest would be to set the datacontext of their grid using placementtarget.
roughly

```
DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=PopUp}"
```

(That bit is air code.)

This is a quick and dirty implementation, still needs a bit of work:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmPvL3r385QhgpgPutGprfx5CBUFBw

The items are indented, so it still needs a bit of work to shift them left AND you probably want a bit of a gap between the columns.

Comment: nvm but why does it look so incomplete ?

Comment: and i don't see any databinding ? How will he even set the headers ?

Comment: I added a bit about the bindings. I don't know that this is really intended to be generic. Maybe the headings are fixed and don't need to be bound at all. Not sure what you mean about incomplete. I don't know enough about what he wants to write the full thing.

Comment: I tried what Andy suggested in a different solution, but i am facing trouble getting the headers and datacolumn getting synced. I have updated the ticket with the implementation what Andy provided. COuld you plz help me in syncying the headers and its corresponding columns.

Comment: You have the SharedSizeGroups set but the parent of everything needs to set Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True".  This can be tricky to get right but you want that on the parent of both grids like in that article.

Comment: And it'll need to be INSIDE the popup. That will have a separate namescope, I think.

Comment: It would be of great help if could provide a sample code or link where combobox with multicolumn headers is achieved. I am stuck with this for about 4 days now.

Comment: I've uploaded a sample, link is in my post above. This is rather quick and dirty but the columns sort of line up with headers.

Comment: Thank you for your valudable feed back, i am working on those. Meanwhile i tried one solution which is uploaded in the google drive link in my question above. I am unable to get the combobox to display in the view after extending it. Would you be able to suggest anything for the same.

Comment: The way a combo works, the thing marked "IsItemsHost" gets all the items. If you put something like a datagrid in that popup then that mechanism isn't going to work. You would need to write some sort of custom control or a usercontrol with textbox and popup. If you fancy that route then you could take a look at this https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Multi-Select-Combo-d4b02a34